# Python 3.3: Hex and Dec converting

Tags: python, hex

I'm able to convert Hex data to Decimal with:

```
file = open("my_text.txt", "r+")
data = input("Type Hex: ")
hex = int(data, 16)
str(hex)
print(str(hex))
file.write(str(hex))
file.close()
input("close: ")
```

But how can I convert Decimal data, like a number or a sentence, to Hex? Also, is it possible to write data to a hexadecimal offset?

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this?

```
>>> print(hex(257))
0x101
>>> for ch in b'abc':
...    print(hex(ch))
...
0x61
0x62
0x63
```

BTW, assigning to a variable called "hex" occludes the built-in function - it's best to avoid that.

HTH

Comment: I can't use hex() because I would use it like I did above, hex(data), and that does not work.